# OpenApi C# responses links

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2019, openapi

Do you know how can I set the links of the response codes in Swagger/OpenApi 3? I couldn't find any documentation that describes how to do it in C# / xml only on yaml which can not be used on Visual Studio
[image]

So far I attempt the following without success:

- /// The request is OK.
- /// The request is OK.
- /// The request is OK.
- /// xxxxxThe request is OK.

Comment: The normal good HTTP Response is "200 OK".  Look at following and do search for "200".  There is also a sample of a failure like 405 :https://swagger.io/specification/

Comment: Hi jdweng: what I am trying to do is add an hiperlink in the links section. Based on what I search, the json can not be modified in order to do that, and the tags that works on yaml does not work on the same what in the xml.